# Magento 2 : SMTP email not received in LIVE site but working in localhost

Tags: email, magento-2.2.5, localhost, smtp

Am using this extension for SMTP email- https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-smtp/ .This extension work perfectly in my localhost but live site its not working and no email are received for forget password. I am using Magento version 2.2.5 .
[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you check the firewall settings of your server/provider to ensure that the outgoing communication is allowed for the used port?

Comment: Please help how to check firewall setting in Cpanel. I used Web-hosting.com